# Flask 404 Error when running on my local machine

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have successfully created my virtual environment and installed flask but everytime I run the program I get  **"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."** when I run it on REPL it works.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<p>Hello Flask</p>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
* Detected change in 'c:\\Users\\mavhu\\Desktop\\Flask_Blogging_App\\main.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 398-868-074
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2020 16:59:06] "?[33mGET / HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2020 16:59:11] "?[33mGET / HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
```

[CODE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xsF3.png)

Comment: Did you by any chance set the SERVER_NAME env variable? In any case, what url do you use when attempting to load the page?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful for others if you could rephrase the question using a question mark sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following steps:

1. Did you use this command before running the Flask app : `set FLASK_APP=main.py`
2. If you are running on Windows, disable any Firewall or AntiVirus solution. Sometimes, they block all such connections on localhost.
3. Also try using the URL `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: I have tried all those steps but nothing seems to work.